problem to execute query with sql_exporter and free/tds in sap iq db
i'm using Prometheus to query some data tables in sapiq DB.
i installed the sql_exporter package and the free/tds package as the connection driver.
executing the sql_exporter.exe file getting error "context deadline exceeded".
The query is a simple select count from table that i executed in interactive-sql and it took 2 sec.
prometheus.yml
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval: 20s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
  scrape_timeout:   10s    # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

# Alertmanager configuration
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
    - static_configs:
        - targets:
          # - alertmanager:9093

# Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
  # - "first_rules.yml"
  # - "second_rules.yml"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: "prometheus"

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:9090"]
      
      
  - job_name: "sql_exporter"

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:9399"]

sql_exporter.yml
# Global defaults.
global:
  # Subtracted from Prometheus' scrape_timeout to give us some headroom and prevent Prometheus from timing out first.
  #scrape_timeout_offset: 500ms
  scrape_timeout_offset: 2m
  # Minimum interval between collector runs: by default (0s) collectors are executed on every scrape.
  min_interval: 3s
  # Maximum number of open connections to any one target. Metric queries will run concurrently on multiple connections,
  # as will concurrent scrapes.
  max_connections: 3
  # Maximum number of idle connections to any one target. Unless you use very long collection intervals, this should
  # always be the same as max_connections.
  max_idle_connections: 3

# The target to monitor and the collectors to execute on it.
target:
  # Data source name always has a URI schema that matches the driver name. In some cases (e.g. MySQL)
  # the schema gets dropped or replaced to match the driver expected DSN format.
  data_source_name: 'tds://username:password@my sapiq ip host address:port/dwhdb'
  
  # Collectors (referenced by name) to execute on the target.
  collectors: [sapiq_test]

# Collector files specifies a list of globs. One collector definition is read from each matching file.
collector_files: 
  - "*.collector.yml"




test_collector.yml
# A collector defining standard metrics for Microsoft SQL Server.
#
# It is required that the SQL Server user has the following permissions:
#
#   GRANT VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO
#   GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO
#
collector_name: sapiq_test

# Similar to global.min_interval, but applies to the queries defined by this collector only.
#min_interval: 0s

metrics:
  - metric_name: test_query
    type: gauge
    help: 'test_query'
    values: [count]
    query: |
       SELECT count(*) from table_name



i checked the prometheus.yml and sql_exporter.yml timers and increased them .problem still exist
in order to check the free/tds i defined in the main.go file of the tds package the same query with same connection string and checked it by go run main.go and successfully queried the sap iq db and i got the row count number .
my tds main.go file
package main

import (
   "database/sql"
    "log"
    _ "github.com/thda/tds" // Importing for side effects to register the TDS driver
)

func main() {
    // Replace with your actual connection details
   // dsn := "tds://user:password@host:port/database"
    dsn := "tds://username:password@my sapiq ip host address:port/dwhdb"

    // Open the database connection using the TDS driver
    db, err := sql.Open("tds", dsn)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error opening database: %v", err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    // Perform database operations
    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error connecting to the database: %v", err)
    }

    log.Println("Successfully connected to the database")
    
    tableName:= "same table name as sql_exporter "
    query :="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + tableName
    
    var count int
 err = db.QueryRow(query).Scan(&count) 
 if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Error executing query: %v", err) }
    
    log.Printf("Number of rows in table %s: %d", tableName, count)
    
} 

in Prometheus is get internal "server error 500"
what can be the reason?
